# RHEL 8 hangs on boot missing disk in fstab

Tags: rhel, boot, fstab, maintenance

my `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=12345abcdef   /data  xfs   defaults  0  0
```

I thought the *0 0* part, one of those, meant skip disk checking so during boot if the disk wasn't there the OS would be ok with it and continue.

In RHEL 8.8 I have that entry in `/etc/fstab` but I have that disk manually removed from the system.
Redhat firsts does the systemd *waiting on whatever* for 1m30s then drops to *hit Ctrl-D for maintenance or enter root password*.

I enter root password, comment out that entry in `/etc/fstab` and reboot and things are fine.

Is there a way to configure RHEL-8 so it doesn't pause for the minute and 30 seconds, and does not drop to maintenance ?  Can it just print a boot message, finish booting, don't delay for more than 2 seconds?

Comment: The last two fields define if a file system needs to be backed up by `dump` and the order in which the disks are checked by `fsck` at boot. They have nothing to do with mounting the device at boot time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, add `,nofail` to mount options.